# $A = \{ x = \{ x_n \} \vert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \vert x_{n+1} - x_n \vert < \infty \}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A = \{ x = \{ x_n \} \in \mathbb{R} \vert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \vert x_{n+1} - x_n \vert < \infty \}$ with norm:
$$ \Vert x \Vert = \vert x_1 \vert + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \vert x_{n+1} - x_n \vert $$

Now, this is norm and I proved it. I want to say that A is a Banach space, so I want to check if it is complete with this norm.

I pick $x_n$ Cauchy sequence in A. 
Then I have $\{x_{n,j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$. Fixing n, I have that $\{x_j\}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$, so it converges. I can then say that my limit candidate is as such:
$$ \exists lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n,j} = x_j$$
I call $x = \{ x_j \}_{j=1}^{\infty}$. I want now to prove that:
$ \Vert x_n - x \Vert \to 0 $ as n $\to \infty $ in the norm defined before.

I start writing:
$$ \Vert x_n - x \Vert = \vert x_{n,1} - x_1 \vert + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \vert x_{n+1,j} + x_{j+1} - x_{n,j} - x_j \vert $$

But now I am stuck, I do not know how to use epsilons to make it go to 0. I think that up to here it is all right though.

Any help?

Comment: I think there is a potential mixup in subscripts going on here.  $x_n$ seems to represent both an element of $A$ and an element of a sequence in $A$.

Comment: I added the subscript j when I want to say the j-th element of the sequence $x_n$. Did I miss it somewhere?

Comment: I was looking at the definition of the norm, which has it there.

Comment: Yes, but then when I say let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence I mean another n. The one in the norm is just an example. I do not know if I have explained myself correctly.

Comment: Shouldn't the last sum be over $j$?

Comment: This normed space is in fact isomorphic to $\ell^1$ via $x \mapsto (x_1, x_2 - x_1, x_3 - x_2, \ldots)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up the notations. First verify that $|x_{n,j}-x_{m,j}| \leq \|x_n-x_m\|$ to show that $x_j=\lim x_{n,j}$ actually exists for each $j$. Now let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $k$ such that $|x_{n,1}-x_{m,1}|+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |x_{n,j+1}-x_{n,j}-x_{m,j+1}+x_{m,j}| <\epsilon$ for $n,m \geq k$. In this inequality let $m \to \infty$ and you get $\|x_n-x\| \leq \epsilon$ for $n \geq k$ where $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$. [ In taking limit as $ m \to \infty$ yuo can take finite sums, say $j$ from $1$ to $N$, take the limit w.r.t. $m$ and then let $N \to \infty$].